# How to detect cursor collision with multiple moving objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, 2d-games

I'm making a game where the player will move using their cursor and will have to dodge objects. Each object has a hitbox, so I want to be able to update the number of lives whenever the cursor hits one. I'm just not sure what an efficient way is to keep track of all the hitboxes. I'd also like to record the object that the cursor collided with, so that bonus objects can be counted. The objects constantly respawn and move off the canvas, so I think keeping an array of all the hitboxes would pretty quickly get out of hand. Here's some code with some pseudo code for what I want to do.

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
  mouseX = e.clientX - rect.left;
  mouseY = e.clientY - rect.top;
  if (somehitboxX<=mouseX<=somehitboxX + 50 and somehitboxY<=mouseY<=somehitboxY + 50){
     doSomething
}

});
```

EDIT: Instead of having my cursor keep track of all the hitboxes, would it be possible to have the hitboxes keep track of the cursor? Maybe by adding an event listener to each object? If that's possible, how would I go about doing it?

EDIT: Here's some code to get a better idea of what I'm working with. The emoji objects are what need to be dodged by the player. Each one has an emoji, a score, coordinates, speed, a hitbox, and a boolean that says whether it's been hit or not (though I'm not sure how to control it yet since that's what I need help with).

```
function Emoji(emojicon, score, x, y, speed) {
  this.emojicon = emojicon;
  this.score = score;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.speed = speed;
  this.hitbox = { hbx: x, hby: y - 50, hbWidth: 50, hbHeight: 50 };
  this.hit = false;
}
```

The emoji objects are initialized like this:

```
  var xPos = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var emo = new Emoji("", 5, xPos, 520, 1);
    emojis.push(emo);
    xPos += 55;
  }
  emojis.forEach(emoji => drawEmoji(emoji));
}
```

And then Emoji.prototype.update updates both the coordinates of the emoji and its hitbox:

```
Emoji.prototype.update = function() {
  if (this.y < 520) {
    this.y -= this.speed;
    this.hitbox.hby = this.y - 50;
  } else {
    var flip = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    if (flip == 1) {
      this.y -= this.speed;
      this.hitbox.y = this.y - 50;
    }
  }
};
```

I hope this is enough code to get an idea of what I have so far.

Comment: You'll have to keep track of the hitboxes one way or another. Just filter out any of the objects that are off the screen maybe.

Comment: You could also take a look at [EaselJS](https://createjs.com/easeljs) or maybe even [Phaser](https://phaser.io/)

Comment: If you want a quick solution consider adding more code so we can test it. It's really hard to guess what your other code might look like and how it comes together with the EventListener shown above.

Comment: @Ivan86 I've added more code to my question